# How to deploy workload with K8s on-demand (GKE)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to deploy a GPU intensive task on GCP. I want to use a Node.js Docker image and within that container to run a Node.js server that listens to HTTP requests and runs a Python image processing script on-demand (every time that a new HTTP request is received containing the images to be processed). My understanding is that I need to deploy a load balancer in front of the K8s cluster that has a static public IP address which then builds/launches containers every time a new HTTP request comes in? And then destroy the container once processing is completed. Is container re-use not a concern? I never worked with K8s before and I want to understand how it works and after reading the GKE documentation this is how I imagine the architecture. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

> runs a Python image processing script on-demand (every time that a new HTTP request is received containing the images to be processed)

This *can* be solved on Kubernetes, but it is not a very common kind of workload.

The project that support your problem best is [Knative](https://knative.dev/) with its per-request auto-scaler. [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) is the easiest way to use this. But if you want to run this within your own GKE cluster, you can [enable it](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/enabling-on-existing-clusters).

That said, you *can* also design your Node.js service to integrate with the Kubernetes API-server to create [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) - but it is not a good design to have common workload talk to the API-server. It is better to use Knative or Google Cloud Run.

Comment: I need GPU processing capability. Cloud run only offers CPU. It needs to be solved on Kubernetes then?

Comment: yes, you can enable Cloud run/knative on your own cluster and use specific GPU nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to accomplish the above w/o using K8s? I have no experience with K8s hence I am asking for alternative solution that does not require using K8s